# Video footage from a 'face down' camera - orientation issue

Tags: video-recording, screen-resolution, orientation

Using a  Samsung S5 Neo (SM-G903F), Android 5.1.1

I have filmed a few short clips, facedown, ie, towards the floor.

I am guessing that this is a Samsung/Android issue, seen as even when I watch the clips in Windows media - they are vertically oriented. Must be a sensor issue?

I have tried filming with the camera both ways (volume buttons towards me, or away from me) and there is no change.

My question is what can I do to return as high Resolution as possible? When i rotate the videos to the correct orientation - I am losing quality (my estimate is from 1920x1080 down to 1080x607, right?).

Are there any tricks that can be done? either at filming or editing stages? So far the only thing i have found, it to start shooting in regular landscape mode, and then pan downwards to wards the floor, and then it plays in the correct orientation.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at VLC Player and the Transform-Options to rotate the video without less quality.

Comment: Flip your screen?!

Comment: Resolution is not the same as view size!